# Task Dependency in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to setup org-capture or org file for following issue:

Task A is the major  task.  It depend upon minor tasks B and Task C.
 Now in org-agenda view, I should be able to see Task B and Task C.
 When they are done, I should be able to see Task A in agenda.  I want to generalize if possible such as Task B can depend upon Task D and Task E.

How I can achieve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `org-enforce-todo-dependencies`.  Here is the help string:

```
org-enforce-todo-dependencies is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is t
Original value was nil

Documentation:
Non-nil means undone TODO entries will block switching the parent to DONE.
Also, if a parent has an :ORDERED: property, switching an entry to DONE will
be blocked if any prior sibling is not yet done.
Finally, if the parent is blocked because of ordered siblings of its own,
the child will also be blocked.
```